# Radioactivity of Promethium

Tags: radioactivity

In school I was taught while looking at the difference between lanthanides and actinides that all of the actinides were radioactive, while only promethium among the lanthanides was radioactive. The question that struck my mind was 'why only promethium'?

On further research I also found out that technetium has a similar behaviour, being located in the midst of stable elements. Why does this happen?